# Proper implementation of pop up contact form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm working on a site and there is going to be a pop up form for a "contact us" link. It isn't anything really fancy, and I didn't want to use any libraries for it as I felt it wasn't too hard to implement myself.
I made the form in its own `div` that is positioned in the middle of the page that has css as `display:none;` until the "contact us" is clicked and then I use a quick js function to set `display:block;` This is all fine and works how I want it to but I want to use php to validate and submit the form to email whatever the message was. My problem is because I have

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

when it is submitted the page refreshes for the request to sent, and my `div` is back to `display:none;` so if there are errors, the user gets no feedback on that. I can just give the contact us and form its own page, but I thought it'd be best for the user to have less pages to go to. So what would be best practice to validate and submit a form without my pop up going back to `display:none;`?

Comment: By using AJAX. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: @yuriy636 oh duh. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nicest solution for user is to validate form with javascript and if valid send to the server using Asynchronous JavaScript and XML (AJAX) with proper loading animation or progress bar and then replace the form with nice confirmation message if everything went well or show error message if didn't. Consider looking for some nice libraries like jQuery and its plugins to help you with this task and you should be able to do it pretty quickly.

You should also make sure that form basic functionality works when javascript is disabled and user gets redirected to a page with the thank you message and try to protect the form against spambots using your preferred method.